# regex for matching literal string combinations

Tags: regex

I'm a noob with regex.

I have to match literally different combinations of strings. Like in the example:

```
"feed the cat."
"feed the dog."
"feed the bear."
```

but NOT

```
"feed the eagle."
"feed the monkey."
"feed the donkey."
```

I tried something like `/^feed the [cat|dog|bear].$/` but it doesn't work. The cheatsheet available on the net explain a lot of complicated things, but not how I can match several strings literally...

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're slightly confusing some syntax. Here's the correct pattern:

```
^feed the (cat|dog|bear)\.$
```

You can also use:

```
^feed the (?:cat|dog|bear)\.$
```

if you don't need to capture the animal name.

The square brackets are used for character classes, like `[a-z]` which means *"any lowercase letter between a and z, in ASCII"*.

Also, note that I escaped `.` with `\.`, because `.` means *"any character except newline"* in regex.

Comment: but parenthesis make groups

Answer (score 2):

You can try following regex,

```
feed the (cat|dog|bear)
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY2rM0/1)